# Inline update statement replace string with variables

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to use an update statement to update a certain record, however I am having difficulty. I would like to replace ‘user’ and ‘timestamp’ with variable values however When I provide inline variables I receive an error, can someone help me to achieve this functionality. I an using sql server as my dbms.

Variables:

```
Dim timeStamp As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")

Dim user As String = GetUserName()
```

Update Statement:

```
strsql = strsql & " Update Activity Set userName = 'user', timeDate = 'timeStamp' Where noteKey = " & lngNoteKey
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) to do this.

```
strsql = strsql & " Update Activity Set userName = @user, timeDate = @date Where noteKey = " & lngNoteKey
```

and then add the parameters to the command when you execute it:

```
yourQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("user", user));
yourQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("date", timeStamp));
```

Comment: Do I add the parameters after the query ? I'm not sure where to add the parameters.

Comment: Honestly I don't think it matters if you add them before or after as long as you add the parameters before you execute the query.  To make it easier to read I would add them after.  Take a look at the link I referenced at the beginning of my answer - they go over how to use parameterized queries start to finish.

Comment: I'll check out the link. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
strsql = strsql & " Update Activity Set userName = '" & user & "', timeDate = '" & timeStamp & "' Where noteKey = " & lngNoteKey
```

Try that. concatenate the data into the string.

Comment: How? He is providing the values in this case. Yes, you shouldn't if it's user provided. I like your answer better. I don't deal much with SQL in VB / VBA so thats my lack of knowledge. I deal with PHP primarily and I know to use data binding.

Comment: This isn't a SQL Injection vulnerability since the input does not come from a user, but if you go this route you should be very careful not to use it when the variables are provided by the user.

Comment: yeah you are right.  Sorry - i undid my down vote and changed my comment.

Comment: I upvoted yours, it's a much better learning experience than a hacked together methods.

Comment: Thanks.  +1, I think either is fine in this situation since the input isn't user provided (assuming `GetUserName()` isn't getting input from user) but probably better to get them in the habit of using parameterized queries